# Display Unsigned zero fill id with leading zero in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to display unsigned zero fill id in laravel blade template. My id has a value of 0001 but displaying in views just 1. This is my code:

```
{{$voters->id}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to pad a string with leading zeroes.

```
{{ str_pad($voters->id, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) }}
```